# Make spring boot + oauth2 work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create a spring+Oauth2+mysql project.
For that, I am referring https://github.com/dsyer/spring-rest-service-oauth.
It works with imMemory Token store, But same is not working when I am changing  it to jdbcTokenStore.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .jdbc(dataSource)
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

         @Bean
            public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
                DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
                tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
                tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
                return tokenServices;
            }

    }
}
```

Checked many tutorials but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the datasource to your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a scheme "oauth2":

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/oauth2
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.schema=oauth2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Test connection every hour Database
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
```

then you only have some like:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
}

. . .
```